# How can I sort by date consistently in the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, sort

I would like to use the "arrange by date" feature of Finder on Mountain Lion (version 10.8.2, all current system updates installed) and view the result in a consistent manner from "newer" to "older".

In [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19019/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-sub-headings-in-finder-with-arrange-be-date-created-in?rq=1) there is an example for what the "arrange by date" option does:

[image: Screenshot of Finder]

In this example (I found the same behavior on my machine) the table sections are sorted with **newer items at the top** and **older items at the bottom**. However, within each table section, the sort order is **newer items at the bottom** and **older items at the top**.

Is there a way to way to arrange everything in a consistent order and keep the sections for grouping the files into date categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in finder, go to "view" in the menubar and then select "Show view options" (or something similar, or alternately just press cmd+J) When presented with the new window configure the options how you like them, and then press the "use as default", and now everything should be consistent.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue -- the "Sort by" and "Arrange by" options are distinct and can be set independently of each other. Setting both indeed resolves the problem, thanks for the solution!